# Django: Sum by date and then create extra field showing rolling average

Tags: django, window-functions, django-orm

I would like to create a Sum in a Model by date and then add a rolling average ... in one query. Is this possible?

Let's say I have a table like this, called "Sales":

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|     Date            |     Category     |     Value    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-01     |         1        |      55.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-01     |         2        |      30.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-02     |         1        |      25.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-02     |         2        |      85.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-03     |         1        |      60.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-03     |         2        |      30.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

I would like to group it by Date (column "Category" is unimportant) and add the Sum of the values for the date. Then I would like to add a rolling Average for the last 7 days.

I tried this:

```
days = (
        Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(sum_for_date=Sum('value'))
        ).annotate(
                rolling_avg=Window(
                         expression=Avg('sum_for_date'),
                         frame=RowRange(start=-7,end=0),
                         order_by=F('date').asc(),
                    )
                )
        .order_by('date')
```

This throws this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Avg('sum_for_date'): 'sum_for_date' is an aggregate
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to compute the average of an aggregate field ('sum_for_date') within the same query. This is not possible with Django's ORM.

One possible workaround is to use a subquery to calculate the daily sums, and then use another query to calculate the rolling average. Here's an example using your Sales model:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum, F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import Lag

# Subquery to calculate daily sums
daily_sums = (
    Sales.objects
    .values('date')
    .annotate(sum_for_date=Sum('value'))
)

# Query to calculate rolling average
rolling_avg = (
    daily_sums
    .annotate(
        rolling_sum=Window(
            expression=Sum('sum_for_date'),
            frame=Window(
                expression=Lag('sum_for_date', offset=6),
            ),
        ),
        rolling_count=Window(
            expression=Sum(1),
            frame=Window(
                expression=Lag('date', offset=6),
            ),
        ),
    )
    .annotate(
        rolling_avg=Window(
            expression=F('rolling_sum') / F('rolling_count'),
            frame=Window(
                expression=Lag('date', offset=6),
            ),
        )
    )
    .order_by('date')
)
```

This first calculates the daily sums using a subquery, and then uses window functions to calculate the rolling average. The rolling_sum window function calculates the sum of the previous 7 days' sums, and the rolling_count window function calculates the count of dates in the previous 7 days. Finally, we divide rolling_sum by rolling_count to get the rolling average.

Note that this approach uses Window functions, which are only available in certain databases (e.g. PostgreSQL). If you're using a different database, you may need to use a different approach to calculate the rolling average.

More information about `Window`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I gave your solution a try and got 2 errors. This first was:  "TypeError: Window.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'". So i deleted "start=0" and now I get this error: 

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('sum_for_date'): 'sum_for_date' is an aggregate

Can you please check your code? I would really like to try your promising answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, have edited my answer. Check it again, please.

Comment: Sorry, still not working: 
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('sum_for_date'): 'sum_for_date' is an aggregate